# Kotlin: problem using autowired class in inheritors

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a class:

```
open class AbstractMapper<E : AbstractEntity, D : AbstractDto> @Autowired constructor(

        protected val mapper: ModelMapper

) : EntityDtoMapper<E, D>
```

It have autowired bean ModelMapper in main constructor. I try to inherit other class from it:

```
class UserParamsMapper : AbstractMapper<UserParams, UserParamsDto>()
```

IDE ask to declare field, autowired in class-paernt:

```
No value passed for parameter ModelMapper
```

Please advice, how to do it? Or I can autowire bean in AbstractMapper other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass all superclass constructor arguments in the subclass constructor. The `@Autowired` annotation is pointless on an abstract class constructor, as it only applies to the constructor of a class that is instantiated itself. You can make this work by changing your subclass:

```
class UserParamsMapper @Autowired constructor(
    mapper: ModelMapper
) : AbstractMapper<UserParams, UserParamsDto>(mapper)
```

Alternatively you can change to field injection instead of constructor injection in your superclass.

```
open class AbstractMapper<E : AbstractEntity, D : AbstractDto> : EntityDtoMapper<E, D> {
    @field:Autowired
    protected lateinit var mapper: ModelMapper
}
```

Comment: Shoul AbstractMapper has @Component?